# Is there a way to use the aws_ec2 ansible inventory plugin to define a prometheus target group dynamicly?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, prometheus

I'm trying to configure a prometheus server working with ansible. I want to monitor some aws instances (ec2) but I'm stuck with the targets of prometheus. I probably should use a json file to define my targets but I don't know how to update the file when I create a new instance with ansible. Also I'm using the aws_ec2 plugin for the dynamic inventory on ansible.

So my question is: how can I use the inventory plugin to keep update the target file of prometheus without doing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can use prometheus service discovery with the same / similar filters that you use for `aws_ec2` inventory. I spent time on this issue as well but am very happy with the outcome. Basic example:

```
scrape_configs:
- ec2_sd_configs:
  - filters:
    - name: tag:Environment
      values:
      - PROD
  job_name: ec2
  relabel_configs:
  - replacement: ${1}.prod.yourdomain.com:9100
    source_labels:
    - __meta_ec2_tag_dnsname
    target_label: __address__
  - source_labels:
    - __meta_ec2_tag_Name
    target_label: instance
- ec2_sd_configs:
  - filters:
    - name: tag:Environment
      values:
      - PROD
  job_name: application_actuators
  relabel_configs:
  - replacement: ${1}.prod.yourdomain.com:9001
    source_labels:
    - __meta_ec2_tag_dnsname
    target_label: __address__
  - source_labels:
    - __meta_ec2_tag_Name
    target_label: instance
  - action: drop
    regex: ^$
    source_labels:
    - __meta_ec2_tag_application
  - regex: (.+)
    replacement: /$1/api/actuator/prometheus
    source_labels:
    - __meta_ec2_tag_application
    target_label: __metrics_path__
```

[ec2_sd_config documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#ec2_sd_config)

This config is generated by `ansible`.